# The bottom few layers printed on Ender 3 are extruded wrong

Tags: print-quality, troubleshooting, creality-ender-3

For some reason, the bottom few layers printed on my Ender 3 are distorted. Used the benchy from http://www.3dbenchy.com/ and Cura 3.6.0, sliced with default settings for Ender 3 on the draft preset. The material is Hatchbox PLA. I think the bed is leveled pretty well, but there might be some adjustments I could make.[image: Warping on the bottom layers]

Comment: Please post an image of the bottom, usually this effect is caused by a too large of a nozzle to bed distance, this question, and the printed result, looks very much like [asked here](/q/8022/).

Comment: It may not be a duplicate as the dup's OP determined that the solution didn't actually resolve the issue.